# Multiple dropdowns to update highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

- edit: I figured out what I need to do, updated fiddle below -

I am using highcharts to plot weather data and would like to give the user the option to 1) choose between three different time periods to display and 2) choose between metric and 'english' units.

My problem: I am struggling with the logic of having two dropdowns to select things from.

Here is a fiddle of my graph. The part that updates the chart is at the end of the javascript. The left dropdown works, the right one (units) does nothing at the moment. My attempt to deal with it is at the end of the fiddle, currently commented out. https://jsfiddle.net/m2ydxs8t/25/

The outline of how I am updating it is like so:

```
//update for time drop down    
$('#timespan').change(function(){
var chart1 = $('#container1').highcharts();
var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts();
var selVal = $("#timespan").val();
if(selVal == '1') {     
...do stuff with chart...
}
if(selVal == '2') {            
...do other stuff with chart...
}
if(selVal == '3') {            
...do other stuff with chart...
}
})
//update for unit dropdown
$('#units').change(function(){
var chart1 = $('#container1').highcharts();
var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts();
var selVal2 = $("#units").val();
if(selVal2 == 'm') {            
...show metric units...
}
if(selVal2 == 'e') {            
...show english units...
}
```

I can't figure out how to get something along the lines of the following, let alone do so elegantly:

```
$('#BOTH OF THEM').change(function(){
var chart1 = $('#container1').highcharts();
var chart2 = $('#container2').highcharts();
var selVal1 = $("#timespan").val();
var selVal2 = $("#units").val();
if(selVal == x and selVal2 == y) {            
...do stuff stuff with chart...
}
```

I am very new to javascript / jquery and suspect that this is a more general problem related to my lack of understanding of js logic than a highcharts specific issue. Links to documentation or even terminology to google for would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Lea, It seems that after uncomment your last funciotn the code is working correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uhLgeco7/

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes it kind of works but only independently of the other dropdown. I probably phrased this poorly. I need them to work together, as in: if "3 days" is selected and I switch units, it should still show 3 days but switch units. I need an "and" condition in there, or a way to make the unit change function get the current data from the series depending on the time period selector and then apply the unit change to that.

Comment: ok never mind, I figured it out, it just seems very round about like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m2ydxs8t/36/